# Text difference transition highlighting react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to make a component to highlight the difference between inputNow and inputBefore for a few ms

**Example:**

you have AAAAA and type in a B, so you have AAAAAB where the B is highlighted, and then the highlighting fades away

Comment: You can iterate over a string like you do an array, with a for() loop for example. Compare each character before and after.

Comment: I also tried this but failed to implement this